# How to change a int to a string like this

Tags: java

I'm trying to change a int to a string and printing it like this.

```
int count;
    for(count = 0; count <= 99;count++)
    System.out.print( count+", ");
    System.out.print(100);
```

It'll be like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

The numbers that are divisible by 3 will be changed to tree.
If it's divisible by 5, it will be "high".
If it is divivisble by both 3 & 5, it'll be "tigh".

1,2,tree,4,high,tree,7,8

I'm stuck on how to change it.

Any help?

Comment: Can't see tree anywhere in your code. What have you tried so far to accomplish it?

Comment: I'm a beginner so I've tried. if(count%number){count = tree) I've searched online and can't get very far

Comment: I think maybe what you need to start with is to concatenate some strings together to make a longer string.  `"1,2,3," + 4` is "1,2,3,4"  That'll get you started.  The "replace" part needs more code on your part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments under this answer, you need to update your existing code and replace it with following:

```
    int count;
    for(count = 1; count <= 99;count++){
    if(count%3==0 && count%5==0 ){
        System.out.print( "tigh, ");
    }
    else if(count%5==0 ){
        System.out.print( "high, ");
    }
    else if(count%3==0 ){
        System.out.print( "tree, ");
    }
    else{
        System.out.print( count+", ");  
    }


    }
    System.out.print(100);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: There should be no comma after the last number (100) and `"tree"+", "` can be replaced with `"tree, "`.

Comment: It worked but I also need disvible by 5 it's high and if it's divisible by 3 and 5 it's tigh. I tried myself but It would repeat the numbers.

Comment: @FernandoMatsumoto Thanks. Updated it.

Comment: @INeedHelp in that case you need to update your question too

Comment: @BalwinderSingh did thanks

Comment: @INeedHelp updated the answer as per your requirement

Comment: `count%3==0 && count%5==0` could easily be `count % 15 == 0`

Comment: @BalwinderSingh It worked! Thanks for the help

Comment: @INeedHelp Glad to help you

Answer (score 2):

From your comment on @BalwinderSingh's comment, it seems similar to FizzBuzz. Here is how I would do it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    if (i % 15 == 0) { // % 3 && % 5
        System.out.print("tigh, ");
    } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
        System.out.print("high, ");
    } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
        System.out.print("tree, ");
    } else {
        System.out.print(i + ", ");
    }
}
System.out.print(100);
```

Comment: It would leave out the others and would only print the tree / high

Comment: @INeedHelp Why? Then it won't meet requirements.

Comment: @MannyMeng your code isn't printing the normal numbers. The else scenario

Comment: @BalwinderSingh good catch.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i =0; i <= 99; i++) {
   if (i % 3 == 0)
      System.out.print("tree, ");
   else 
      System.out.print(i + ", ");

}
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, some explanation of what was changed and why may be of more help than a naked code post. Further, this doesn't actually address most of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's a little complicated but I wanted to be unique:

```
for (int count = 0; count <= 99; count++) {
    System.out.print(count % 3 == 0 && count % 5 == 0 ? "tigh, " : (count % 3 == 0 ? "tree, " : (count % 5 == 0 ? "high, " : count + ", ")));
}
System.out.println(100);
```

Comment: There shouldn't be a comma after 100. That's why its out of the loop, in a separate `System.out.print(100);` statement in the OP's code. Also, the output is supposed to be in one line instead of 100 lines (replace `println` with `print`).

Comment: Proper formatting would go a long way in making that reeadable... if wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Or this way

```
    System.out.println(IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 100)
            .mapToObj(i -> i % 15 == 0 ? "tigh"
                          : i % 5 == 0 ? "high"
                          : i % 3 == 0 ? "tree"
                          : String.valueOf(i))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
```

(which does not compile in Eclipse due to a bug it seems: http://ideone.com/KZ79pk works)

By the way.. 100 is divisible by 3 and 5. So if you're cheating, don't `println(100)` :)